# How do I use the sender in a GridView RowCreated event to see if an Gridview Button was fired?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a GridView which has plus ImageButtons in one column. 
I need to check if any of the plus ImageButtons were fired or not in the RowCreated event of the said Gridview. 
How do I go about it?

Comment: Hey, did it help, or are you still havin' problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to check if a button was clicked during event that created it.  If my understanding of the page life cycle is accurate, a siplified version of your event log would look something like this:

//new row created

//post-back is triggered

- Page_Load event
- Row_Created event

//client clicks button

//post-back is triggered

- Page_Load event
- Button_Clicked event

This means that all your buttons will always be un-clicked during the Row_Created event.  The best way to tell if a button was clicked is to create an event handler for it. Just keep in mind that clicking a button triggers post-back even if it has no event handler.

Also jmodrak, the sender of the Row_Created event is the GridView that the row was created for.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you, but without code, you never can feel certain enough, still...

Using the `is` keyword, you can check the type of sender.

```
if(sender is ImageButton)
    Console.WriteLine("BUTTON CLICKED");
if(sender is Label)
    Console.WriteLine("LABEL CLICKED");
```

Then, if you wish to work with the properties of `sender`, eg. if it is a `ImageButton` and you want to know which `ImageButton` exactly was clicked, simply go like this

```
var button = sender as ImageButton;
string buttonName = button.Name;
```

Comment: No bud, it didn't. I went with a client side approach and it worked. Thanks anyway. :)